# Requested unknown parameter '2' from datatable

Tags: java, jquery, json, datatable

I am using Jquery Datatable with server side processing in order to process all my data. My parameter '2' is a date, which I enter in as a String, convert to a Date to add to the database, however, use a String again to display to the webpage. This works fine for 'GetData' process. However, when I enter in a new dataset using 'AddData', I get the error in the title. It seems that only the two columns that deal with Date are throwing this error, the rest of the row gets written. As soon as I refresh the page, everything does back to normal.

This is my datatable script:

```
var i = 0;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            oTable = $("#datatables").dataTable({
                        "aoColumns" : [
                            { "sName" : attendingPhysician" },
                            { "sName" : "physicianName" },
                            { "sName" : "dateStart" },
                            { "sName" : "dateEnd" },
                            { "sName" : "teamNumber" }
                         ],
                        "sAjaxSource" : 'teamassignmentdata',
                        "sServerMethod": "GET",
                        "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
                            //The call to makeEditable is set here to make sure all the data are loaded
                            i++;
                            if(i == 1) {
                                this.makeEditable({
                                    sUpdateURL : 'UpdateTeamAssignmentData',
                                    sAddNewRowFormId: "formAddNewRow",
                                    sAddNewRowButtonId: "btnAddNewRow",
                                    sAddNewRowOkButtonId: "btnAddNewRowOk",
                                    sAddNewRowCancelButtonId: "btnAddNewRowCancel",
                                    sAddURL: "AddTeamAssignmentData",
                                    sAddHttpMethod: "POST",
                                    aoColumns : [
                                         {},    //physician number; default editing 
                                         {},    //physician name; default editing
                                         {      //date start; datepicker
                                            type : 'datepicker',
                                             datepicker : {
                                               dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                                             }
                                         },             
                                         {
                                            type : 'datepicker',
                                             datepicker : {
                                               dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                                             }
                                         },     //date end; datepicker
                                         {  //team number; no editing
                                            indicator: 'Saving...',
                                            tooltip: 'Click to edit team number',
                                            loadtext: 'loading...',
                                            type: 'select',
                                            onblur: 'submit',
                                            data: "{'5':'5','6':'6','7':'7','8':'8','9':'9'}"
                                         }  
                                     ],
                                    height : "20px"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

        });
```

And this is the method that is actually entering the data into the database, and outputting it to the datatable.

```
String physician = request.getParameter("physician");
    String physicianname = request.getParameter("physicianname");
    String datestart = request.getParameter("datestart");
    String dateend = request.getParameter("dateend");
    String team = request.getParameter("team");
    boolean addSuccess = true;

    PhysicianTeamData physicianTeamData = new PhysicianTeamData();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "(team_attendingPhysician, team_physicianName, team_dateStart, " + 
            "team_dateEnd, team_teamNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
    int returnId = 0;
    try {

        dateStart = dateFormat.parse(datestart);
        dateEnd = dateFormat.parse(dateend);

        sqlDateStart = new java.sql.Date(dateStart.getTime());
        sqlDateEnd = new java.sql.Date(dateEnd.getTime());

        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(physician));
        ps.setString(2, physicianname);
        ps.setDate(3, sqlDateStart);
        ps.setDate(4, sqlDateEnd);
        ps.setString(5, team);

        returnId = ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addSuccess = false;
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if(addSuccess) {

        PhysicianTeam pt = new PhysicianTeam();
        pt.setRecordNumber(returnId);
        pt.setAttendingPhysician(Integer.parseInt(physician));
        pt.setPhysicianName(physicianname);
        pt.setDateStart(datestart.toString());
        pt.setdateEnd(dateend.toString());
        pt.setTeamNumber(Integer.parseInt(team));

        physicianTeamData.addPhysicianTeamData(pt);

        //out.print(returnId);
        out.print(pt);

    } else {
        out.write("Row Add Failed!");
    }
```

PhysicianTeamData is just an arraylist, and these are the fields in PhysicianTeam class:

```
private int attendingPhysician;
private String physicianName;
private String dateStart;
private String dateEnd;
private int teamNumber;
```

Like I mentioned, the JSON object puts dateStart as parameter '2' and dateEnd as parameter '3', both of which are throwing error, even though I am outputting them as a String.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could it be that just the name of the parameter in the request might be wrong, ie. `datestart` instead of `dateStart`

Comment: the request gets datestart though doesn't it? From this line: pt.setDateStart(datestart.toString());, the date that's being set to the object is a string, and that is outputted. I'm sure it's a small thing, just can't pinpoint it